# Using parallel in R for whole scripts

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a question regarding parallel computation of whole scripts. My script imports data, than splits by random in a train and validation dataframe, does a preprocessing and validation. I want to iterate the same script with many different seeds.

Is it possible to do this in parallel? The scripts don't interfere with each other.

```
seeds <- c(2343242,324256,764865,3524526,574574,75624,15436,674767,4325265,2462626,
           245264,647474,2465374,4253532,5787462,35636,357484,34524,74859,1352637)

for (i in 1:length(seeds))
  {
  set.seed(seeds[i])
  seed <- seeds[i]
  print(seeds[i])
  
  print("begin import")
  source(file = "import.r")
  print("preprocessing")
  source(file = "preProc.r")
  print("normal")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets.r")
  print("resampled")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets up down.r")
  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any of `parallel::parLapply` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbatim one-to-one solution:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

seeds <- c(2343242,324256,764865,3524526,574574,75624,15436,674767,4325265,2462626, 245264,647474,2465374 (but not ,4253532,5787462,35636,357484,34524,74859,1352637)

empty <- future_lapply(seeds, function(seed) {
  set.seed(seed)
  print(seed)
  print("begin import")
  source(file = "import.r")
  print("preprocessing")
  source(file = "preProc.r")
  print("normal")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets.r")
  print("resampled")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets up down.r")
})
```

Unless those seeds you've picked are essential is some way, you probably wanna use statistically sound parallel RNG instead, which you get automatically if you do:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

set.seed(42) ## Optional to fix the initial seed
n <- 20L     ## Number of runs

empty <- future_lapply(1:n, function(ii) {
  print(.Random.seed)
  print("begin import")
  source(file = "import.r")
  print("preprocessing")
  source(file = "preProc.r")
  print("normal")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets.r")
  print("resampled")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets up down.r")
}, seed = TRUE)
```

Since we're not making use of `ii` here, the latter could equally well be using a futurized version `base::replicate()`:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

set.seed(42) ## Optional to fix the initial seed
n <- 20L     ## Number of runs

empty <- future_replicate(n, {
  print(.Random.seed)
  print("begin import")
  source(file = "import.r")
  print("preprocessing")
  source(file = "preProc.r")
  print("normal")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets.r")
  print("resampled")
  source(file = "algorithms and datasets up down.r")
})
```

PS. It's not clear to me how you distinguish the results from the different runs.  Maybe you rely on `seed` to save to different files in those scripts.

Comment: Hey @HenrikB, looks like an awesome package! I save the results in the scripts in a vector with reference to the seed and with rbind in each iteration. Maybe you can help me with an issue: when I'm executing the code, I have a RAM problem. The script usually needs 16GB of RAM on my 32 RAM Notebook. So the script stops immediately with "cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Mb".

Comment: If you run out of memory, you need to profile where RAM is consumed (e.g. profvis package) and see if you can decrease memory usage, e.g. release/remove unused objects.  You need to do that in sequential mode.  If you still run out of memory, you need to use fewer number of parallel workers.

Answer (score 1):

Rstudio has a very reliable, easy and intuitive way of running parallel scripts called **Background jobs**. The following [link](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/tools/jobs.html) explains how to use it, but in summary, everytime you run a script, it runs in paralel, using multiple cores and it usually goes much faster (if the CPU and RAM are not super busy). There are two ways to use Background Jobs, the manual and the scripted:

1. The manual way: you just open the *background job* and select the script and the working directory. Then you can choose to save the global environment or not. If your script already exports or save the objects at local, then do not worry about that.
2. The scripted way: you can use [JobRunScript](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/jobRunScript.html) to create background jobs with code. Therefore you can automate the changes you want from the scripts.